# Android Studio Update to 2.3.3

Tags: android

I updated the android studio to 2.3.3 from 2.2.3 now when opening the existing projects it shows the following error.

Error:Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin/1.3/android-maven-gradle-plugin-1.3.pom'. Received status code 407 from server: Proxy Authentication Required
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

How to fix it? Can anyone help.

Comment: As the error said 'Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project'. Have you tried this.